# Is there a possibility to bring a widowed old parent to Germany if “hardship” is proven?

Tags: visa, germany, residency, dependent-visa, non-residents

My mother is in Sri Lanka, and is widowed and old. She is financially and emotionally dependent on me. I am working in Germany on a 3 year blue card. If I prove my mother's hardship, is there a way to bring her and make her stay until mine? I consulted a German immigration lawyer and he denied immediately saying its not possible and that I'll only waste the money. But in the law I have read that if "hardship" is experienced, adult dependents could be brought over. I can sponsor mom for all her needs including insurance and any other cost. Is there any one who has done this or who could provide me an advice as to whether there are any chances of succeeding at all? Last few days have been hopeless, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The easier thing might just be to get a PR/become a citizen and then move with your mother to another EU country. Funny that while local laws might deny entry to parents, EU law states that they should be able to join. At least that's what I've read about the current state of affairs.